# Make multiple select on one column with different WHERE

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
ID,date,state    
1,2015-04-04,1    
1,2015-05-04,0
```

and I would like to make a request like this:

```
SELECT 
(YEAR(date)) AS year_A, 
(MONTH(date)) AS month_A, 
(count(*)) AS number_A,
(count(*) WHERE state = 0) AS number_B
(count(*) WHERE state = 1) AS number_C
 FROM A_transaction GROUP BY year_A, month_A
```

to get something like this

```
year_A,month_A,number_A,number_B,number_C    
2015,04,2,1,1
```

But this doesn't work. I think the problem is from the WHERE clause

Comment: It's not much of a data set fir us to work with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write your query using conditional aggregation (i.e. `COUNT` only when a condition is true). This will give you the results you want:

```
SELECT YEAR(date) AS year_A, 
       MONTH(date) AS month_A, 
       count(*) AS number_A,
       count(CASE WHEN state = 0 THEN 1 END) AS number_B,
       count(CASE WHEN state = 1 THEN 1 END) AS number_C
FROM A_transaction 
GROUP BY year_A, month_A
```

Note you don't need to enclose expressions in parentheses. They just make your query harder to read.

Note also that standard MySQL date format is `YYYY-MM-DD` which means that the two sample dates in your table are actually in different months, and the output of the query is

```
year_A  month_A number_A    number_B    number_C
2015    4       1           0           1
2015    5       1           1           0
```

If your dates are in `YYYY-DD-MM` format, you will need to convert them using `STR_TO_DATE` e.g.

```
SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%Y-%d-%m')) AS year_A, 
       MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%Y-%d-%m')) AS month_A, 
       count(*) AS number_A,
       count(CASE WHEN state = 0 THEN 1 END) AS number_B,
       count(CASE WHEN state = 1 THEN 1 END) AS number_C
FROM A_transaction 
GROUP BY year_A, month_A
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8LuAuUFT6s1crL8pSB4sfR/0)

Comment: Thanks a lot you solve my problem. Also I made a mistake with the date format  it was good

Answer (score 1):

MySQL makes it very easy to get aggregated columns like these, because it evaluates expressions like `state = 0` to `0` (`false`) or `1` (`true`). 
So you don't need `CASE..WHEN` and you can do it like this:

```
select 
  year(date) as year_A, 
  month(date) as month_A, 
  count(*) as number_A,
  sum(state = 0) as number_B,
  sum(state = 1) as number_C
FROM A_transaction 
GROUP BY year_A, month_A
```

Comment: I usually write these MySQL queries like this too, it's a lot cleaner. I stuck with `COUNT` because that's what OP was using.